# (fixed) Missing character: There is no ( ("28) in font nullfont! after updating latex packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

update: this problem has been fixed in tkz-euclide ver. 4.00.

original post:
After updating texlive packages recently (2021/11/15), I found there are some curiuous warnings when using tkz-euclide, which doesn't occur before

MME:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){P}
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](P,O)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "testmini.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\TeXTemp\TeXAux

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(d:/TeXTemp/testmini.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-12>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.sty
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-euclide.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-base.sty
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryangles.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryarrows.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarybabel.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarycalc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.t
ex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.markings.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.shapes.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.shapes.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.text.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.text.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryintersections.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryintersections.c
ode.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)))

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypatterns.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarypatterns.code.t
ex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryplotmarks.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.
tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryquotes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshadows.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryfadings.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.te
x)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.misc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.m
isc.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarythrough.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/numprint/numprint.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
No configuration file `numprint.cfg' found.)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))
Local configuration file tkz-base.cfg found and used
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-base.cfg
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-base.cfg
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-modules.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-utilities.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-lib-marks.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-lib-symbols.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-base.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-base.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-utilities.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-utilities.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-math.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-math.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-text.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-text.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-BB.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-BB.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-arith.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-arith.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-print.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-print.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-misc.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-misc.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-axes.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-axes.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-grids.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-grids.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-marks.tex
2020/03/18 3.07c tkz-obj-marks.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-points.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-points.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-rep.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-rep.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-intersections.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-intersections.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-angles.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-angles.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-angles.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tool-eu-angles.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-arcs.tex
2020/03/23 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-arcs.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-compass.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-compass.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-circles.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-draw-circles.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-polygons.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-by.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-tools-eu-points-by.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-protractor.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-protractor.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-sectors.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-sectors.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-show.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-show.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-triangles.tex
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-obj-eu-triangles.tex
)) (./testmini.aux) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
Missing character: There is no ( ("28) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no P ("50) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) ("29) in font nullfont!
[1] [2] (./testmini.aux) )
Output written on testmini.pdf (2 pages).
SyncTeX written on testmini.synctex.

Transcript written on testmini.log.
```

updated packages:
[image]

Comment: the warning was there earlier too, you only see it now better as it shows up in the terminal too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how good is your French? ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622637/1090

Answer (score 5):

As Ulrike commented the warning was there previously but only to the log file, latex has increased the default value of `\tracinglostchars` so that the missing character warning is more visible. (In real cases it results in missing text in the result, although here it is spurious path parsing errors)

The actual underlying error appears to be the definition of `\tkz@DefLine` in `tkz-euclide` that inserts a second () group after `\tkzDefOrthLine` which is only defined to take one such group:

`\def\tkz@DefOrthLine[#1](#2,#3){% ...`

So removing the second () makes the warning go but I couldn't work out what the intended definition was. (at this point `#2` is `P,O` so `(#2,\tkz@through)` is not right either).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\def\tkz@DefLine[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/tkzDefLine/.cd,K=1}  
\pgfqkeys{/tkzDefLine}{#1}  
\ifcase\tkz@numl%
 % first case 0
 \tkzDefMediatorLine(#2)  
  \or% 1
  \tkzDefOrthLine[\tkz@koeff](#2)% this makes a warning (\tkz@through)  
  \or% 2
   \tkzDefLineLL(#2)
  \or% 3
  \tkzDefBisectorLine(#2)
  \or% 4
  \tkzDefBisectorOutLine(#2)
  \or% 5
  \tkzDefSymmedianLine(#2)
  \fi    
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

aaa\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){P}
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](P,O)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the `(#2)` is right. At first all the other cases use it too, and at second it is what is currently used by the code, and nobody complained about wrong lines ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but #2 is the coordinate pair from (P,O)  the second `(\tkz@through)` is the point specified by the option `[orthogonal=through P]` presumably this is supposed to do something:-)

Comment: if you look the internal code, `\tkz@DefOrthLine` then you can see that it uses \tkz@through, so it doesn't need to get it passed as argument.

Comment: ahah good plan. I'll maIl Alain.... @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Yes you are right. This error was corrected a few months ago but I haven't had time to finish the new version of tkz-euclide. I hope to finish the documentation of the new version soon. \tkz@through was not necessary and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @AlainMatthes thanks for confirming!